# Angular directly returning api requests and shareReplay

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am confused about the returning of external calls in Angular services. In the official docs they seem to immediately return http.get calls from a service (https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#services) e.g:

```
 getHeroes() {
   return this.http.get('api/heroes').pipe(
   map((response: Response) => <Hero[]>response.json()));
 }
```

However, I would like to add a shareReplay so the call gets executed only once.

I made a stackblitz to describe the situation more clearly.

I guess my question is if this is the correct way of returning such an observable:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kwkwcx

Answer (score 0):

you can use a behaviour subject to store cache

```
cachedData=new BehaviorSubject(null)

getNormalData () {
    return this.http.get('https://swapi.co/api/people/1')
    .pipe(tap(cachedData.next));
}
```